# react native init error stay in node postinstally

Tags: node.js, react-native

i fllowed the steps refer to the offical articles,but there is something wrong like this

This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/meyou/object/hello

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /Users/meyou/object/hello/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
>   node-gyp rebuild

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /Users/meyou/object/hello/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
>   node-gyp rebuild

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node

> spawn-sync@1.0.13 postinstall /Users/meyou/object/hello/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync
>   node postinstall

|

the cursor was lling bling for a whole day

Comment: yes ,i google it,and also search is in the stackoveflow and github with site:

Comment: Which node version are you using?

Comment: node4.1.0     -----------as it puts "at least node 4.0 or newer"